# Verifying conformal generators generate conformal transformations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

Given the finite conformal transformations

[image: Test]

My simple, and really algebraric, question is, how do you actually compute $\text{exp}(ia^\mu P_\mu)$? What I have done:
$$e^{a^\mu\partial_\mu}x^\nu=(1+a^\mu\partial_\mu+O(\partial^2))x^\nu=x^\nu+a^\mu\delta_\mu^\nu=x^\nu+a^\nu.$$
So far so good.
$$e^{i\alpha D}x^\nu=(1+\alpha x^\mu\partial_\mu+O(\partial^2))x^\nu=x^\nu+\alpha x^\nu=(1+\alpha)x^\nu.$$
Is it correct that there doesn't need to be a 1-1 correspondence between generators and transformations? Like $e^{\alpha D}x^\mu$ does not generate $\alpha x^\mu$.

Comment: Your action of $D$ is incorrect. The corrections are $O((x \cdot \partial)^2)$ which contains a linear term as well so act non-trivially on $x^\nu$. You cannot neglect them. PS - you need $( x \cdot \partial )^n x^\mu = x^\mu$ for any $n$.

Comment: Thats only because we're in euclidean spacetime, right? Isn't the correction $(x^\mu\partial_\mu)^2$?

Comment: No. It holds in any signature. There are infinitely many terms in the correction. The exponential function has a whole Taylor expansion that you need to use to derive the action in D. you can’t just stop at the linear or quadratic level.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on the [Lagrange shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), essentially a formal summary of the Taylor expansion. You know its result given your summary of translations.

For just one variable, you found
$$
e^{a\partial_x} f(x) = f(x+a).
$$

Now note for $y\equiv \ln x$,
$$
e^{ax \partial_x} f(x) ~~~\leadsto \\
e^{a \partial_y} f(e^y) =f(e^{y+a})=f(e^a~ x),
$$
so your $\alpha=e^a$.

You can take it from here, appreciating *D* is scaling only the rotationally invariant "radius" of $x^\mu$.